# How can you create a login and a user but only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql script to create a login and user as follows:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyPassword',
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyNewDatabase],
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english],
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
CHECK_POLICY=OFF

USE [MyNewDatabase]
GO

CREATE USER [MyLogin] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[MyLogin]
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, MyLogin;
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, MyLogin;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [MyLogin]
GO
```

However, I only want all of this to happen if the login doesn't exist. If I try and wrap it in a 'IF NOT EXISTS....BEGIN...END' it wouldn't work as the GO statements would override it. I need the  'GO' after the login so it can then be used for the creation of the user. So how can I make sure the login doesn't exist before trying to create both login and user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support syntax such as `CREATE {object} IF NOT EXISTS`. It *did* introduce `CREATE OR ALTER` syntax in SQL Server 2017, however, that is only for objects where the object `CREATE` statement must be the only one in the batch.

For objects that don't need that, such as a `LOGIN` and `USER`, you can check if the object exists using an `IF` and `NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```sql
USE master;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [name] = N'MyLogin')
    CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin]
      WITH PASSWORD=N'MyPassword',
           DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyNewDatabase],
           DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english],
           CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
           CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
USE [MyNewDatabase];
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = N'MyLogin')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [MyLogin] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[MyLogin];
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER MyLogin; --Don't use sp_addrolemember is has been deprecated for some time
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER MyLogin; --Don't use sp_addrolemember is has been deprecated for some time
END;
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this approach, as in a duplicate check. I was hoping it wouldn't be necessary. I did read that potentially you could set 'no exec' on if you effectively wanted it to 'stop' but that sounds like a hack.

Comment: Actually won't this fail on the second part? I only want it to create the login if it doesn't exist, but I only want it to create the user if the login DOES exist. I'm also assuming I should have a 'BEGIN...END' wrapped around the CREATE LOGIN part.

Comment: *"Actually won't this fail on the second part?"* It'll only fail if a *different* `USER` exists for the `LOGIN` named `MyLogin`, @sr28 ; otherwise the statement will either not run because a `USER` of the same name already exists or will create the `USER` for the `LOGIN` (whether the `LOGIN` was created in the previous batch or not). As the `LOGIN` is created in the prior batch if it doesn't already exist, the `LOGIN` itself will always exist for the `USER` creation statement.